# Azure function app docker image vulnerability issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, azure-functions

We have dockerized and hosted our azure function app in Kubernetes(Google Cloud Platform). When scanning the docker image which was moved to artifact registry in GCP, we are facing following docker image vulnerability issues.

[image]

We have created `dockerfile` from Visual Studio, by choosing the respective project and right click->Add->Docker Support option. Refer the code snippet of our `dockerfile`,

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0 AS base
>
> WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
>
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-alpine AS build
>
> WORKDIR /src
>
> COPY ["../.csproj", "src/../"]
>
> RUN dotnet restore "../.csproj"
>
> COPY . .
>
> WORKDIR "/src/src/.."
>
> RUN dotnet build "../.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
>
> FROM build AS publish
>
> RUN dotnet publish "../.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
>
> FROM base AS final
>
> WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
>
> ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot 
> AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
>
> COPY --from=publish ["/app/publish", "/home/site/wwwroot"]

Also, they are suggested to try this fix.

[image]

We tried this fix using this command, `RUN apt-get install -y libtasn1-6=4.13-3+deb10u1`, but this command throws error as it can't find the package. Can anyone give some suggestions to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you try with this command `apk add <your_package_name>=VERSION-SUFFIX>`. Before installing also run `apk update` and see if it pulls in the right version?